# Adding in brackets for JSON in R

Tags: r, json, dplyr

I have this sample JSON:

```
[
  {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "latitude": "41.8781",
    "longitude": "87.6298"
  }
]
```

How can I use R to transform that into regular JSON? (As in, not an array). I want this:

```
library(jsonlite)

{
  "Chicago": {
    "lat" : "41.8781"
    "long" : "87.6298"
    }
}
```

I used the `jsonlite` package to convert a dataframe into JSON, eg `toJSON(df, pretty = T)`. Sample data set:

```
df <- tibble(
  "City" = ("Chicago"),
  "latitude" =(41.8781),
  "longitude" = (87.6298)
)
```

There's a few hundred of these, any help would be great. Or, if it is not possible within R, that would be good to know, too. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the first example an array with one structure element? Can't you dereference that element? (Like a[0] vs a[[0]])

Comment: Pretty much zero experience in JSON, especially within R, so... maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- fromJSON('[
    {
        "city": "Chicago",
        "latitude": "41.8781",
        "longitude": "87.6298"
    }
]')

ans <- setNames(apply(df[,-1L], 1, as.list), df[,1L])
toJSON(ans, auto_unbox=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the `setNames` statement? It works on the singular example, but when I run it on my entire set I get this error: `Error in df[, 1L] : incorrect number of dimensions`. Curious to how I would adjust / if I need a for loop

Comment: Actually got it to work, had to make it JSON, and then go back